# How to re-render component instead of calling constructor?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a FlatList with items with progressbars and i want to change the progress of one item. For the progressbar I made a custom component. But everytime i change the progress of one item, he item re-renders but the omponent does not re-render, instead the constructor gets called. That is problematic because of the progress animation.

I tried adding functions like componentWillReceiveProps and componentWillUpdate but those don't get called.

The item:

```
<View style={styles.node}>
  <PercentageBar value={item.progress} />
</View>
```

The Component:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animHeight: new Animated.Value(this.props.value),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.animHeight,
      {
        toValue: this.props.value,
        duration: 200,
      }
    ).start();
  }

<View style={styles.background}>
  <Animated.View style={{height: this.state.animHeight.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
          }}></Animated.View>
</View>
```

Instead of the constructor being caled and resetting the component I want it to re-render with the new props.

Comment: Are you using keys so React knows it's still the same item? Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Oh thank you, a thought that keyExtractor on index is enough. It works now with key on item-name but that is not unique. Should i generate random keys now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to run by inserting a conditional statement as shown below.

example.js

```js
componentDidUpdate(){
   if(true){
   ...
  }
}
```

OR

You can render it again each time you change the code.

example.js

```js
render{
//your code
return();
}
```

program operating sequence
[image]